Flutter Html with IntrinsicHeight
I have a problem caused by IntrinsicHeight when i use html. But, it runs fine if I use Text.
html says that it needs a specific height (can't be dynamic). Whereas, I need dynamic height.
Here is my code :
Widget getContent() {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Container(
      child: ListView.separated(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = dataReview[index];
          final comment = item['comment'];
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
                  child: Text(
                    item['name'],
                    style: textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  item['date'],
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) ...[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          iconStarSolid,
                          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                            i <= 5 - item['rating']
                                ? Colors.black12
                                : Colors.amber,
                            BlendMode.srcIn,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),
                  child: VisibilityWidget(
                    visible: item['review'] != null,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                      child: Html(
                        data: '<html><head></head><body><p>"Very very bad."</p></body></html>',
                        style: {
                          'body': Style(
                            margin: Margins.zero,
                            lineHeight: LineHeight.number(1.3),
                          ),
                        },
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: comment != null,
                  replacement: Container(),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                    child: ContainerShadow(
                      color: primaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                      paddingVertical: 16.0,
                      paddingHorizontal: 16.0,
                      child: IntrinsicHeight(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: VerticalDivider(
                                color: primaryColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                                width: 1.0,
                                thickness: 2.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        height: 35.0,
                                        child: FittedBox(
                                          child: CircleAvatar(
                                            backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                              iconCharger,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 12.0,
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Admin',
                                          style: textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                                            color: primaryColor,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                  Text(
                                    comment != null ? comment['date'] : '',
                                    style: textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                                  Container(
                                    child: child: Html(
                                      data: '<html><head><title>Page Title</title></head><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>',
                                      style: {
                                        'h5': Style(
                                          margin: Margins.zero,
                                          lineHeight: LineHeight.number(1.3),
                                        ),
                                      },
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                    ),                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider(
            height: 5.0,
            thickness: 1.5,
            color: Colors.black12,
          );
        },
        itemCount: dataReview.length,
      ),
    );
  }

return VisibilityWidget(
      visible: !loading,
      replacement: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 70.0),
        child: AnimateLoadingWidget(),
      ),
      child: VisibilityWidget(
        visible: isShowRatingRecap,
        replacement: Container(
          child: EmptyWidget(
            image: placeholderWarning,
            description: 'Empty.',
          ),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              getHeader(),
              getContent(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

expected result :
click here for the image of my expected result
how can i get dynamic height for html when i use IntrinsicHeight?
or maybe there are other options to achieve my goals (drawing vertical line & use html in same time)?

I made a widget for this that dynamically calculates the height of HTML using InAppWebView:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview
You basically wrap your html content inside a div and put an observer inside the script tag like this:
 String htmlContainer = """<html lang="en">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width user-scalable=no zoom=1.1">
        <body>
        <div><div class="htmlWrapper container" id="_flutter_target_do_not_delete">${state.htmlContent}</div></div>
          <script>
            function outputsize() {
              console.log(document.getElementById("_flutter_target_do_not_delete").offsetHeight);
                window.postMessage('flutterTargetHeight', document.getElementById("_flutter_target_do_not_delete").offsetHeight);
            }
            new ResizeObserver(outputsize).observe(_flutter_target_do_not_delete)
            outputsize()
        </script>""";

state.htmlContent in this case is my html which i want to display (so only what is inside the body). Depending on your case you may remove the parent tags (html, meta, etc.) so that you have valid html.
My InAppWebView widget looks like this:
InAppWebView(
            onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
              if (url?.uriValue != null &&
                  url!.uriValue.path != "blank" &&
                  await canLaunchUrl(url.uriValue)) {
                await controller.stopLoading();
                await launchUrl(url.uriValue);
              }
            },
            initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: state.htmlContent),
            initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
                verticalScrollBarEnabled: false,
                transparentBackground: true,
                javaScriptEnabled: true,
                disableHorizontalScroll: false,
                supportZoom: false),
            onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
              double? height = double.tryParse(consoleMessage.message);
              if (height != null) {
                context.read<FlexibleWebviewBloc>().add(
                    FlexibleWebviewEventAdjustHeight(
                        height: height + FlexibleWebview.additionalHeight));
              }
            },
          ),

Set javaScriptEnabled to true and inside the onConsoleMessage message you can get the height of the widget. Since i used Bloc for state management i fire an event with the calculated height. You may just call setState or whatever you use:
double? height = double.tryParse(consoleMessage.message);
                  if (height != null) {
                    context.read<FlexibleWebviewBloc>().add(
                        FlexibleWebviewEventAdjustHeight(
                            height: height + FlexibleWebview.additionalHeight));
                  }

I also had to add some additionalHeight to the calculation (which in my case is set to 28). Maybe comes from the default paddings of body tags, etc.
Not sure if thats still the case, but the observer fired the events frequently. So you should also check that you don't do unnecessary builds if the height is the same.
